# What is Elixir way of matching the same values in a function clause?

Tags: elixir

For example, in Erlang:

```
1> (fun(A,A) -> same_values_only end)(7,7)
same_values_only
```

I naively tried the caret in Elixir but it was a no go:

```
iex(3)> (fn(a,^a) -> :same_values_only end).(7,7)           
** (CompileError) iex:3: unbound variable ^a
```

The obvious solution works of course

```
iex(2)> (fn(a,a) when a == a -> :same_values_only end).(7,9)
** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in :erl_eval."-inside-an-interpreted-fun-"/2

iex(2)> (fn(a,a) when a == a -> :same_values_only end).(7,7)
:same_values_only
```

but I was wondering whether there is a solution closer to how it works in Erlang at the top?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's the same as in erlang - using a variable multiple times in a pattern enforces it has the same value in all occurrences.

```
fn(a, a) -> :same_values_only
```

The pin operator allows enforcing a previous value of a variable. Pattern matches are not evaluated from left-to-right, but rather as a whole expression, so no variable is bound until the pattern matches.

Comment: Apparently I am an idiot and should have gone to sleep hours ago... Thanks